# axes labels not displaying on 3d subplots

Tags: matlab, mesh, label, axes, subplot

I have created 5 3D subplots which include a for loop. However, the labels of the X and Y axes are not displaying for some reason. I would appreciate any help on this matter. Below is the code.

On a separate note, any suggestions to make the figure more aesthetically pleasing would also be much appreciated.

```
% parameters
b=0.5;
O=27;
x=1:1:5;

% energies 
e1 = 1:1:100;
e2 = 1:1:100; 

% function
[e1,e2]=meshgrid(e1,e2);

hb=@(x)((O.^2)./factorial(O-x)).*...
    exp(-b.*O.*e2);

hu=@(x)(O.^x).*...
    exp(-b.*O.*e1);

p=@(x)hb(x)./(hb(x)+hu(x));

f=figure('visible','on')
clf(f);

for i=x
    subplot(2,3,i);
    mesh(e1,e2,p(i))
    title(['X = ',int2str(i)], 'FontSize',12);

    % log all axes
    set(gca, 'XScale', 'log');
    set(gca, 'YScale', 'log');
    set(gca, 'ZScale', 'log');

    axis([1 100 1 100 10^-300 1])
    axis square
    grid off 
    set(gca,'FontSize',10)

    xlabel('e1')
    ylabel('e2')
    zlabel('p_{H}')
end
```

Comment: That's weird. They show up, if you take the rotation tool and rotate the plot. At some certain directions they will shortly pop up. Also they are always visible, if you don't set the ZScale to log. If you ask me, that sounds like a weird Matlab bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be something internal to MATLAB with how it is setting the position of the x and y labels when a 3D surface plot is used. This doesn't happen with a basic `plot3` plot. If you do a `get(get(gca,'Xlabel','Position'))`, you see that the z coordinate of the label is set to infinity, which I would guess is the problem.

I've come up with a less than ideal workaround, but it seems to accomplish the task:

```
% parameters
b=0.5;
O=27;
x=1:1:5;

% energies 
e1 = 1:1:100;
e2 = 1:1:100; 

% function
[e1,e2]=meshgrid(e1,e2);

hb=@(x)((O.^2)./factorial(O-x)).*...
    exp(-b.*O.*e2);

hu=@(x)(O.^x).*...
    exp(-b.*O.*e1);

p=@(x)hb(x)./(hb(x)+hu(x));

f=figure('visible','on');
clf(f);

for i=x
    subplot(2,3,i);
    mesh(e1,e2,p(i))
    title(['X = ',int2str(i)], 'FontSize',12);

    % log all axes
    set(gca, 'XScale', 'log');
    set(gca, 'YScale', 'log');
    set(gca, 'ZScale', 'log');

    axis([1 100 1 100 10^-300 1])
    axis square
    grid off 
    set(gca,'FontSize',10)
    xlabel('e1')
    ylabel('e2')
    zlabel('p_{H}')
    set(get(gca,'xlabel'),'Units','Normalized','Position',[0.75 0 0])
    set(get(gca,'ylabel'),'Units','Normalized','Position',[0 0.05 0])
end
```

You'll probably have to manipulate those position vectors to get the labels exactly where you'd like.

I would also submit a bug report and see what MathWorks says.

Comment: Ok, great, thanks a lot. I guess as long as it that does the job!